# Socket connection getting close while creating room on kurento

Tags: reactjs, maven, spring-boot, websocket, kurento

I have configure kurento on WS. Its spring boot application running on https://localhost:8443 (tomcat).

Logs:

```
s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https)
DEBUG 4730 --- [apterApp.main()] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
INFO 4730 --- [apterApp.main()] com.io.AdapterApp   : Started AdapterApp in 14.041 seconds (JVM running for 29.346)
```

Start boot application using below command:

**sudo mvn compile exec:java Dkms.url=ws://io-storage:8888/kurento**

Websocket running on 8888 port. (not secure WS).

While creating room the request is **ws://io-storage:8888/call**

But getting following error while request send to the kurento server

```
2018-10-31 13:12:23,252181 2009 [0x00007fe37ce5b700]   error KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:455 openHandler()  Invalid path "/call", closing connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Kurento Media Server doesn't listen for RPC commands on the `/call` endpoint. Why are you requesting that URL?

Just use the [Java API client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kurento/kurento-client/6.9.0) by following any of the [Java tutorials](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-helloworld.html); this library does all of the RPC commands for you.

If you still need to work without libraries and program directly against the RPC API, then check [the protocol docs](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features/kurento_protocol.html).